# Get Subject and grade from string

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Given this string

> result = '''Check here to visit our corporate website
> Results
> Candidate Information
> Examination Number
> 986542346
> Candidate Name
> JOHN DOE JAMES
> Examination
> MFFG FOR SCHOOL CANDIDATES 2021
> Centre
> LORDYARD
> Subject Grades
> DATA PROCESSING
> B3
> ECONOMICS
> B3
> CIVIC EDUCATION
> B3
> ENGLISH LANGUAGE
> A1
> MATHEMATICS
> B3
> AGRICULTURAL SCIENCE
> OUTSTANDING
> BIOLOGY
> A1
> CHEMISTRY
> B2
> PHYSICS
> C5
> C Information
> Card Use
> 1 of 5'''

How can I extract the NAME(JOHN DOE JAMES, SUBJECTS and the GRADES to different list.

I have tried this for the subject and grades but not giving me the desired results. Firstly, where subject name is more than one word it only returns to last 1 eg instead DATA PROCESSING am getting PROCESSING. Secondly, it is skipping AGRICULTURAL SCIENCE(subject) and OUTSTANDING(grade)
Please note that am new in using regex. Thanks in advance.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'[A-Z]+\n{1}[A-Z][0-9]')
searches = pattern.findall(result)
if searches:
    print(searches)searches = pattern.findall(result)
for search in searches:
    print(search)
```

> **OUTPUT FOR THE FIRST PRINT STATEMENT**:

['PROCESSING\nB3', 'ECONOMICS\nB3', 'EDUCATION\nB3', 'LANGUAGE\nA1', 'MATHEMATICS\nB3', 'BIOLOGY\nA1', 'CHEMISTRY\nB2', 'PHYSICS\nC5']

> **SECOND PRINT STATEMENT**

PROCESSING
B3
ECONOMICS
B3
EDUCATION
B3
LANGUAGE
A1
MATHEMATICS
B3
BIOLOGY
A1
CHEMISTRY
B2
PHYSICS
C5

Comment: This is not a regex problem.  Look for the separators, 'Name', 'Examination', 'Grades'.  Given the location of those strings, you can extract each section.  In the grade section, split it into words and look for the two-letter words.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this without using regexes.  Note that I am assuming "OUTSTANDING" is intended to be a grade.  That takes special processing.

```
result = '''Check here to visit our corporate website Results Candidate Information Examination Number 986542346 Candidate Name JOHN DOE JAMES Examination MFFG FOR SCHOOL CANDIDATES 2021 Centre LORDYARD Subject Grades DATA PROCESSING B3 ECONOMICS B3 CIVIC EDUCATION B3 ENGLISH LANGUAGE A1 MATHEMATICS B3 AGRICULTURAL SCIENCE OUTSTANDING BIOLOGY A1 CHEMISTRY B2 PHYSICS C5 C Information Card Use 1 of 5'''

i = result.find('Name')
j = result.find('Examination',i)
k = result.find('Centre')
l = result.find('Subject Grades')
m = result.find('Information Card')

name = result[i+5:j-1]
exam = result[j+12:k-1]
grades = result[l+15:m].split()

print("Name:", name)
print("Exam:", exam)
print("Grades:")
subject = []
for word in grades:
    if len(word) == 2 or word=='OUTSTANDING':
        print(' '.join(subject), "......", word)
        subject = []
    else:
        subject.append(word)
```

Output:

```
Name: JOHN DOE JAMES
Exam: MFFG FOR SCHOOL CANDIDATES 2021
Grades:
DATA PROCESSING ...... B3
ECONOMICS ...... B3
CIVIC EDUCATION ...... B3
ENGLISH LANGUAGE ...... A1
MATHEMATICS ...... B3
AGRICULTURAL SCIENCE ...... OUTSTANDING
BIOLOGY ...... A1
CHEMISTRY ...... B2
PHYSICS ...... C5
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your quick response.. And for the fact that you avoided regex as much as possible. But I think the code might have issues when any string content changes..that not withstanding. This will help me allot. Thanks once again

Comment: Well, that's the key point, right?  If you hope to do automated text processing, then you MUST have "guideposts" that let you identify the pieces of information.  Otherwise, you're just looking at random data, and there's no way to turn that into "information".  Right?  Your scheme of extracting all the capital letters doesn't separate the name from the exam from the test center.